# XAML trigger for tristate variable in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got a `bool?` in my `ViewModel` that binds to two `RadioButtons` in my XAML.

I would like the first `RadioButton's` `IsChecked` to be set to `True` if the property is either `true` or `null`, and the second `RadioButton` to be set to the inverse of that. I just can't seem to find a way to get this to work while updating the property in the `ViewModel`.

Here's my current XAML which does not really work:

```
<RadioButton Name="RadioButtonDhcpConfig" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="DHCP" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
    <RadioButton.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding DhcpEnabled}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DhcpEnabled}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </RadioButton.Resources>
</RadioButton>
<!--Row 2-->
<RadioButton Name="RadioButtonManualConfiguration"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Content="Manual Configuration:" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
    <RadioButton.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding DhcpEnabled}"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DhcpEnabled}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DhcpEnabled}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DhcpEnabled}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </RadioButton.Resources>
</RadioButton>
```

If I remove all the `DataTriggers` from the second `RadioButton` the setter for `DhcpEnabled` is called when the first `RadioButton` is clicked (as expected) but the the XAML above the setter is never called.

The problem here is that I need to ensure that my `DhcpEnabled` property is set to `false` when a user clicks the second `RadioButton` and can't figure out a way to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered putting this logic in the viewmodel? I would think it'd be more readable.

Comment: @Andy wouldn't that require me to end up with two distinct properties, one per `RadioButton`? Which would end up also meaning extra code to ensure that there's no scenario where they are either both false or both true (although both null is fine).

Comment: Try a converter instead, for the first one convert null to true and for the second one create inverter so every false would be true.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a converter for your first button:

```
public class Bool2NullConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return value == null;
        }
        if (value is bool?)
        {
            return (value as bool?).Value;
        }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

You would then use this in your `RadioButton` like this:
`<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding DhcpEnabled, Converter={StaticResource bool2Null}}">`
All you need to do now is to reverse the logic of the first converter to make it an inverter and apply that to the second `RadioButton`. It will make XAML a lot cleaner as well.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. For the first Radio Button you would set the default value to true, and then use a trigger to change it when the value is false. For the second control you simply bind it to be opposite of the first control.

```
<RadioButton Name="RadioButtonDhcpConfig" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="DHCP" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
    <RadioButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DhcpEnabled}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </RadioButton.Style>
</RadioButton>
<!--Row 2-->
<RadioButton Name="RadioButtonManualConfiguration"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Content="Manual Configuration:" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
    <RadioButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=RadioButtonDhcpConfig, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </RadioButton.Style>
</RadioButton>
```

Comment: This doesn't call the setter of `DhcpEnabled`, which is required.

Answer (score 0):

Add an inverted property in the viewmodel (or use a converter):

```
private bool? dhcpEnabled;

public bool? DhcpEnabled
{
    get => dhcpEnabled;
    set
    {
        if (dhcpEnabled != value)
        {
            dhcpEnabled = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DhcpEnabled));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DhcpDisabled));
        }
    }
}

public bool? DhcpDisabled
{
    get => DhcpEnabled == false;
    set => DhcpEnabled = !value;
}
```

**Then in XAML:**

Pay extra attention to the `GroupName` attribute.

```
<RadioButton x:Name="RadioButtonDhcpConfig"
             GroupName="MyDhcp"
             Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="DHCP"
             VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"
             IsChecked="{Binding DhcpEnabled}"/>
<RadioButton x:Name="RadioButtonManualConfiguration"
             GroupName="MyDhcp"
             Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
             Content="Manual Configuration:"
             VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"
             IsChecked="{Binding DhcpDisabled}"/>
```

Comment: This doesn't call the setter of `DhcpEnabled`

Comment: Please see update. Also, consider using an enum instead of a nullable boolean.

Comment: Actually this still doesn't work. For a slightly different reason. The `DhcpDisabled` is a property of `SelectedNetworkAdapter` which the user can change. The radio buttons are wrapped around a `Grid` and its `DataContext` is set to `SelectedNetworkAdapter`. What this means however is that if `DhcpDisabled` is set to `True` and I change the `SelectedNetworkAdapter` to something else that has `DhcpDisabled` as `False`, the getter of `DhcpDisabled` will be called, the `IsSelected` of `RadioButtonManualConfiguration` will change and with it the setter of `DhcpDisabled` will be invoked again.

Comment: Which in other words will mean that it will call `DhcpEnabled = !value` and `value` happens to be `false` so it will set `DhcpEnabled` back to `true`.

Comment: If the buttons are in a group then the `disable` button doesn't have to be bound to anything. It will just reset the first one which will automatically set it to false.